# How convert String.UTF8View.Index to String.CharacterView.Index?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7, swift2

I'm handling with String in swift.But when I want to convert  String.UTF8View.Index to String.CharacterView.Index,I got some trouble.Anyone knows how to do?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following init function:

```
String.Index.init(utf8Index: UTF8Index##UTF8Index#>, within: <#T##String#>)
```

You must user String as parameter in this function.